# How to download SemanticUi offline documentation

Tags: semantic-ui

I am a beginner and I am trying to learn  about semantic ui css framework.
    So anybody please tell me.How can i download offline documentation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the Semantic-UI Documentation repo from Github. 
Here's a link: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Docs

Answer (score 2):

Install https://zealdocs.org/ and you can download their documentation offline using the tool

Comment: Works on Raspbian OS  10 (buster) as well